# Delphi : losing focus from parent when clicking on child

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I am having a problem with an effect trigger (shadow effect). I did put the trigger to be `ismouseover = true`. So, when I put the mouse onto a panel (parent), the shadows activate, and it works fine until I start putting some buttons inside the panel (children).

The shadows effect goes off when the mouse is over the children.

So, is there anyway to keep focus on the parents while being focused on the children?

I did try to change the trigger of the effects (from `ismouseover` to `isfocused`), but it didn't give any different results.

Comment: Keyboard focus is designed to work this way. Your design is wrong... you need another layer of indirection to manage when the window should be displaying special effects, such as checking whether any child windows have focus, plus caveats

Comment: An alternative would be to use window-less buttons, then they can't steal input focus. Otherwise, consider tracking the mouse's movements manually and just check on each movement whether the mouse has entered/left the panel's bounding rectangle

Comment: If you opt for windowless buttons, don't forget that you still need to make your GUI keyboard usable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said, your design is wrong, then you can remove the trigger and do it manually :

```
// show or hide shadow effect
procedure TForm2.ShowShadowEffect(AValue: boolean);
begin
  if ShadowEffect1.Enabled <> AValue then
    ShadowEffect1.Enabled := AValue;
end;

// show when enter on panel
procedure TForm2.Panel1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowShadowEffect(True);
end;

// hide when leave the panel
procedure TForm2.Panel1MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowShadowEffect(False);
end;

// keep visible when over button
procedure TForm2.Button1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowShadowEffect(True);
end;
```